# Circle graph algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms

You are given N points on 2-D plane. How can I find out minimal radius of a circle which contains at least M of these points?

algorithm for code

I searched for smallest enclosing circle problem but that was not for at least m?

Answer (score 5):

See

Sariel Har-Peled and Soham Mazumdar (2005), "Fast algorithms for computing the smallest $k$-enclosing circle", *Algorithmica* 41 (3): 147–157, [doi:10.1007/s00453-004-1123-0](http://doi.org/10.1007/s00453-004-1123-0).

Answer (score -5):

This is a N algorithm

1. Given a set of N points P, draw a line that have at least M points at one side of it.
2. Name this subspace with at least M points as S
3. Pick a point that lays in S and call it center
4. Calculate the most distant point from center and call the distance as ray.

There you go, you have circle with a center and a ray.

Obs. the way you chose the center is what determinates the size of your circle

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Comment: There is no reason why this algorithm gives the circle with the smallest radius.